# How do I stop the second floor of my house from being so hot in the summer and so cold in the winter

Tags: insulation

I have a window AC upstairs in the summer but it is not enough I can fell the heat coming off of the ceiling in the summer and in the winter it is way to cold that my kids have to sleep downstairs please help

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your problem is insufficient attic insulation. In the summer, your attic gets hot, and that heat radiates down into the second floor. In the winter, your attic gets cold, and sucks heat out of your house, aided by the stack effect. Improving the insulation on your attic flow will help both of those problems. The typical approach is to blow cellulose into the attic floor. But be careful! If your house is old and there's already any blown insulation, it might be asbestos-laden vermiculite. You might want to consult a pro. Often it's barely more expensive to hire this job out than to do it yourself.

Comment: In my case, most of the cost of having a pro both do this and air-seal my place (which is arguably the single most cost-effective energy conservation you can take) was covered by my utility company. Check what rebates you might be eligible for.

Comment: True, although air sealing comes with more complication since the better you do it, the more you need a mechanical ventilation system to be added, which is another kettle of fish.